# How do i store the results from a while list in variables and print the data?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, sentinel

So this short program is designed to allow the user to input scores and then the program calculates the weighted average of the quizzes, programs, and exams. Basically the output of the program needs to look like this, the portions that are bold are the portions that are inputed by the user, the rest is done by the program. (an input of "-1" will break the loop and move on to the next bit of code)

This is all supposed to be done with while loops and sentinels, no dicts or lists should be needed.

```
Quiz #1 ----- 10
Quiz #2 ----- 9.5
Quiz #3 ----- 8
Quiz #4 ----- 10
Quiz #5 –---- -1

Program #1 -- 9.5
Program #2 -- 10
Program #3 -- 9
Program #4 -- -1

Exam #1 ----- 85
Exam #2 ----- 92
Final Exam -- 81

Average ----- 89.4
Grade ------- B
```

Initially i thought that each Quiz was already programmed in to the code but now i realize he wants a while loop that adds to the quiz number each time. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to print that out AND save the data in the variables i need to compute the average at the end.

TL;DR - This should be able to be completed using only while loops and it's driving me crazy, is there a way to write a loop where the variable changes from "Quiz #1 ------ " to "Quiz #2 ----- " while still storing the values that i put in each time through the loop?? Right??

Comment: Ask your buddy for help.

Comment: dude I'm just trying to get some help here, I can't figure this out